# Как сделать связь М:М, где в связывающей таблице будет еще одно поле?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, hibernate

Имеются 2 сущности: `user` и `achievementtype`. Требуется связать их связью M:M, но в связывающую таблицу добавить еще одно поле. Как это сделать?

В сущности user имеется такая конструкция:

```
@ManyToMany
@JoinTable(name = "achievement",
        joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "achievement_userid")},
        inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "achievement_achtypeid")}
)
private Set<AchievementType> achievementTypes = new HashSet<AchievementType>();
```

В сущности achievementtype:

```
@ManyToMany
@JoinTable(name = "achievement",
joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "achievement_achtypeid")},
    inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "achievement_userid")}
)
private Set<User> users = new HashSet<User>();
```

Как получить связывающую таблицу с полями:

```
achievement_userid
achievement_achtypeid
achievementlevel
```

Спасибо.

Comment: Не могу понять, как оно должно связываться. Разные юзеры могут иметь сразу несколько достижений и каждое из достижений ранжируются по уровню достигнутого?

Comment: @pavlofff примерно так

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Никак не получить. В JPA не предполагается наличие дополнительных полей в связующей таблице.
Есть вариант сделать из этой таблицы Enity, которая будет ссылаться на две другие и иметь ещё своё поле. Две другие Entity будут видеть друг друга опосредованно через эту связующую.
Ещё можно получить доступ к этому полю посредством нативных запросов.